# blur event does not get fired

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make drop down purely using JS.
My code is this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
    .smallImg{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #target{
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="src">
<img class="smallImg" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
<div id="target">
<img class="smallImg" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">Target</img>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<p>Hi this is used to get away focus</p>
</div>
<script>
(function(){
var src= document.getElementById('src');
var target =document.getElementById('target');
src.addEventListener('click',function(){target.style.visibility='visible';},false);
target.addEventListener('blur',function(){target.style.visibility='hidden';},false);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking src div my target is set visible, but when I loose focus on it by clicking "Hi this is ...." text , my target div is not hiding.

No error in the console too.
What I am doing wrong and how can I do it correctly ?

Comment: Use `focusout`/`mouseout`, div don't have `blur` event

Comment: You can also use the `tabindex="0"` attribute on the div.

Comment: @Tushar - firefox doesn't have the `focusout` event at all

Comment: img tag shouldn't be closed like that !!! what is this ?!?!?! </img> !!! and a text inside ???????

Comment: @Tushar - using mouseout would mean that you just have to pass the mouse over the div and it would trigger, that's not the same as blur/focusout

Comment: @Tushar mouseout did the trick partially. However how to deal with focus , a element can have focus even when mouse is not on it.

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade That's just a sample app. Don't bother about the semantics. Remove text inside img still it don't solve.

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I solve it than I have tried `focusout` and `blur` both they don't work.

Comment: @Xufox has the answer - add tabindex="0" to the div

Comment: @user3769778 Have you tried the `tabindex` attribute? Only when that attribute has a number other than `-1` as the value, an element becomes focus-able and blur-able.

Comment: see demo http://jsfiddle.net/cysutfqp/

Comment: @Xufox @user3769778  Have tried `tabindex="0"` , that too is not working !

Comment: @Jaromanda X that helped. I got it now. Tab index was necessary and is the solution.